# Another blog formatting error

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, blog

From [The Death of Meta Tags](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/):

[image]

There are >> for the new paragraph, ** for bold, and _ for italic.

Comment: @nicael nope. It used to have line breaks: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:D3O8mk6DyZ0J:blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk.

Comment: [There's how all the thingz should look!](https://web.archive.org/web/20130626001359/http://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Comment: @Sha Just got it.

Comment: Too quick for me, @nic ;)

Comment: Send a pull request https://github.com/StackExchange/blog/blob/master/_posts/2010-08-07-the-death-of-meta-tags.markdown

Comment: @random a what? I don't do github (although I have git installed).

Comment: You create a GitHub account, fork the blog repo, edit the formatting error and send it in as a fix. Then you can label the propsed changes with an equally vague titile https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code (and really the posts) for the [Stack Exchange blog is now openly hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/StackExchange/blog/).

On the blog they mention an [open ear policy to any issues, fixes or improvements you may have](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/07/the-new-stack-exchange-blog/):

> If you have suggestions for how to make the new blog better, create an issue and one of our developers will take a look at it (probably me). If you're a developer, we encourage you to take a look at the source code and make pull requests for changes as well.

Typos and minor formatting bungles like this don't seem at all like they fall outside of empowering yourself to send in a [pull request to fix it](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/).

Comment: Hmm thanks :) I submitted one... I had to use html tho as it wasn't accepting markdown... :/

Comment: just a heads up, I mentioned you on SO's meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302302/1947286

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing out - this was actually resolved with this [commit](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/commit/d41f15cfeffeebd7a68c098d3778b0811ae3f889).